# How do I add another directory for my python modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

My modules have downloaded into two separate folders. One is recognised and the other is not. How can I add the one which is not recognised to python so I can use both? If you can only have one path, how can I change the directory path altogether? Many thanks!

When I've tried to do 'PYTHONPATH' stuff right into the anaconda prompt it's just given me errors, so I'm slightly confused. For some background I'm slightly clueless with this tech...

Comment: `When I've tried to do 'PYTHONPATH' stuff right into the anaconda prompt it's just given me errors,` what have you tried?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I've just tried what the answer tells me to do (the temporary solution, as I don't have admin on my laptop to make it permanent), and while I don't get an error with that, it's not changing anything for me

Comment: @JRiggles Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Remember, when working with environment variables and paths, make sure to use the correct syntax for your operating system (Windows, macOS, Linux).*

**Adding Folders to PYTHONPATH**

The PYTHONPATH environment variable is a list of directories where Python looks for modules and packages. You can add your unrecognized folder to this path to make its modules accessible.
Open Anaconda Prompt and try the following:

```bash
set PYTHONPATH=C:\path\to\unrecognized\folder;%PYTHONPATH%
python
```

Replace C:\path\to\unrecognized\folder with the actual path to your folder. This should add the folder to the PYTHONPATH temporarily for the current session. After this, when you run python, it should recognize modules from that folder.

**Permanent PYTHONPATH Addition**

If you want to permanently add the unrecognized folder to your Python environment, you can set the PYTHONPATH in your system's environment variables.
Right-click on "This PC" or "My Computer" and select "Properties."
Click on "Advanced system settings" on the left.
Click the "Environment Variables" button.
Under "System variables," click "New" and set the variable name to PYTHONPATH and the value to the path of your folder.
Click "OK" to close all the windows.
After making this change, restart your Anaconda Prompt or any Python session, and the folder should be recognized.

**Changing Directory Path**

If you'd like to organize your modules differently, you can consider moving all your modules into a single folder or reorganizing them in a way that both folders are recognized. You can also use virtual environments to manage different sets of packages and modules.
To create a virtual environment using Anaconda, you can use the following commands:

```bash
conda create -n myenv
conda activate myenv
```

Then, you can install packages within this environment, and the Python interpreter will only see the packages installed in that environment.